# Secure page with SSL in Apache and Document Root

Tags: security, apache, ssl, xampp

i created the certificates with OpenSSL for use in localhost.

Fine, but when I set VirtualHost in Apache, if I set DocumentRoot the page is loaded normal, without a different mark in address bar.

When I don't specify a DocumentRoot, the Firefox load the Xampp page, but with secure mark in adress bar.

My actual Vhost is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine On
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

ServerName www.agurbana.com.br

SSLCertificateFile "E:/agenda.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "E:/server_unsecured.key"

SSLCACertificatePath "E:/"
SSLCACertificateFile "E:/ca.crt"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|pl|asp|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

DocumentRoot "E:/SITES/AU2/"
ErrorLog "E:/error.log"
<Directory "E:/SITES/AU2/">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>

BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

how I can do appear a secure mark in address bar when i set up DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 0):

By chance, do you also have a vhost set-up to listen to port:80 in your httpd-vhosts.conf file?

In that case, the scheme will be determined by the user, not by the server. You can get rid of the :80 listener, but now the user has to remember to type https, which is bad. Therefore use Apache re-directs to force usage of SSL, e.g. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-apache-force-https-secure-connections.html